# Access PostgreSQL large objects with pl/python

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

Is it possible to access PostgreSQL large objects with pl/python using the [client interface](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/lo-interfaces.html) function for large objects? 
Just calling the [server-side](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/lo-funcs.html) functions from within the pl/python using [plpy.execute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpython-database.html) seems rather limited.